# Linting error using string literal union types in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I am using a type that only allows three string values. When I use this function and pass it a parameter of the given type (IdPrefix) I get the linting error in VSCode.

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IdPrefix'.

The linting error suggests that I have to define my alternative values as strings but that is not how it is defined according to the [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) website. I think I may need to add something to the line "docId: newId("doc")," to inform typescript that the function resolves as string? Although I defined the output type in the function and would expect typescript to get it from there.

### Details

The function below is used to generate an id for a typed object

## The Function used

```
export interface IdPrefix {
  prefix: "doc" | "vew" | "usr";
}
export const newId = (prefix:IdPrefix) : string=> {
  cnt.update((val) => {
    const newCnt = val + 1;
    return newCnt;
  });
  let derivedId
  id.subscribe(val =>{
    derivedId = val
  })
  return prefix+":_"+derivedId
};
```

## The object created that uses the above function

```
import { newId } from "../countStore";

interface Document{
  docId:string,
  createDate:Date,
  createdBy:string,
  title:string
}

const doc1:Document = {
  docId: newId("doc"),
  createDate: new Date(),
  createdBy: "487601f8-dd3d-4006-982c-2f2e1206a427",
  title: "Which Bycycle should I buy",
};
```

Comment: The return type string in your newId function should not be capitalized

Comment: Thanks! Although I still have the problem when I make that change in VSCode. The linting error is now "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IdPrefix'." I just changed the code above to reflect your advice.

Comment: Why are you passing `"doc"` instead of `{prefix: "doc"}`?  Your `IdPrefix` isn't string-like at all, it's an object with a property named `prefix`.  Do you need someone to explain the difference between object types and `string`, or is this a typo?  How should we proceed?

Comment: Great! Yes that is correct I was trying to figure out how to set my string as a prefix but  I couldn't find the syntax to do that I replace docId: newId("doc"), with docId: newId({prefix: "doc"}) is what I need. Thank you! If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as done